# Curve fit for fft dplot

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency

I have data from accelerometer (time domain) and convert it to fft using Fourier Transform. However, I need to do the curve fit to the plot. 
Can somebody share with me the coding.I don't know how to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need to perform curve fitting? Are you using MATLAB for your work?

Comment: What model for the curve fitting? Do you want to apply it on the FFT or Time Samples?